# Not getting attributes from form elements

Tags: html, post, flask

I have a Flask application, where I'm trying to retrieve some information from my HTML form, however, I don't get any info, and I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

Routes.py

```
@app.route("/about", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def about():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    lastname = request.form.get('lastname')
    msg = Message(
       subject='Hello ' + str(name),
       sender='kristofferlocktolboll@gmail.com',
       recipients=
           ['kristofferlocktolboll@gmail.com'],
       html= 'hello mr ' + str(lastname))
    mail.send(msg)
    confirm_msg = "Your message has been sent!"
    return render_template("about.html", confirm_msg=confirm_msg)
```

about.html:

```
 <h1 class="mb-5"> Enter your message, and i will get back to you as soon as possible</h1>

          <form action="{{ url_for('about') }}" method="POST">
                First name: <br>
                <input type="text" name="name" size="35"><br>
                  Last name:<br>
                 <input type="text" name="lastname" size="35"><br>
                    Email-address: <br>
                 <input type="email" name="email" size="35"><br>
                 Phone-number: <br>
                 <input type="text" name="phone" size="35"><br>
                Enter your message: <br>
                 <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea><br>
            </form>
            <br>
            <form>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" value="submit" method="POST">Let's get in touch</a>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>        
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want it to be a post request, but whenever I remove the 'GET' attribute from my methods in my @app.route I get a "METHOD NOT ALLOWED" error, it might be due to the fact, that it is using GET to redirect.

The email is sent successfully, so the mail API is working fine. But it is sent with the values 'None' where the name and last name attribute where to be.

EDIT:
I have to cast the name and last name objects to a string, otherwise, I will get a Nontype error

Comment: Create two seprate methods for getting the input and sending it back , Your about.html takes the input so render it in diffrent method after getting values.

Comment: so i should not render template after the mail is sent?

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: how do i create two seperate methods?

Answer (score 0):

Create `template/my-form.html`

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="name">
    <input name="lastname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On your flask appplication `routes.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    name = request.form['name']
    lastname = request.form['lastname'] 
    <do your manipulation>
    return render_template(yourtemplate,processedtext = processedtext,somethingelse=somethingelse)
```

you can grep the vaiables in your second rendering template as

```
<html>
<body>
  {{processedtext}}
  {{somethingelse}}
</body>
</html>
```

and display them